# Determine if an SQL statement writes the database in Qt

Tags: sqlite, qt4, prepared-statement

How can I check if a prepared query makes direct changes in the database?

I use SQLite which provides the [sqlite3_stmt_readonly()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt_readonly.html) function,

but can this be done in Qt's side, ie `QSqlQuery`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- `QSqlQuery::numRowsAffected()` which returns the number of direct changes done by the last executed query (it uses `sqlite3_changes()`),
- executing the query `"SELECT total_changes()"` which returns the direct and indirect changes.
- adding `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.c` to your project and use [`QSqlResult::handle`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qsqlresult.html#handle) to call `sqlite3_stmt_readonly()` yourself.

Comment: alexisdm, I'd like to do the check before executing the query. The 3rd option is what I'd probably do, though I was not looking for an SQLite specific solution.